# Update background automatically in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am making an iOS app and It is based on a UITableView. I set the background so that when there is no TableViewCell, the background is a custom background. And when there are TableViewCells, the app changes the background to the color. The problem is, the app has to be force-quit and restarted for the background to change. Is there anyway that I can do this so that is automatically updates the background? Here is my code:

```
// Check if table view has any cells
int sections = [self.tableView numberOfSections];
BOOL hasRows = NO;
for (int i = 0; i < sections; i++)
    hasRows = ([self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i] > 0) ? YES : NO;

if (sections == 0 || hasRows == NO)
{
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background-app.png"]];

}
else
{
 self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
}
```

I put this in my viewDidLoad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! Basically, I put the following code in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
// Check if table view has any cells
int sections = [self.tableView numberOfSections];
BOOL hasRows = NO;
for (int i = 0; i < sections; i++)
    hasRows = ([self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i] > 0) ? YES : NO;

if (sections == 0 || hasRows == NO)
{

    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background-app.png"]];
}
else
{
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
}
```

what I had to do was put this code in my `viewDidLoad`

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background-app.png"]];
```

and put the code at the very above, in my `controllerDidChangeContent` like the following

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    // Check if table view has any cells
    int sections = [self.tableView numberOfSections];
    BOOL hasRows = NO;
    for (int i = 0; i < sections; i++)
        hasRows = ([self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i] > 0) ? YES : NO;

    if (sections == 0 || hasRows == NO)
    {

        self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background-app.png"]];
    }
    else
    {
        self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
    }
}
```

so it loads with the background picture "background-app.png" when the app starts. Then as soon as it recognizes that there is data within the app, it automatically changes to the normal white background. Then when you delete all data, it goes back to the background picture "background-app.png".

Answer (score 1):

Is `self.view` and `self.tableView` the same view object?

You're setting an image to be the background of `self.tableView` and a color on the background of `self.view`. If the table view is a subview of `self.view`, once you set the background image, it will always obscure the background color of `self.view`.

Force quitting probably works because you re-run your logic and never set the image background in the first place. Try setting the table view's background view to `nil`:

```
if (sections == 0 || hasRows == NO)
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background-app.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    // Set the background view of the table view
    self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView;
}
else
{
    [[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];   
    self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question to include what you have given me and I changed the color of the background to be self.tableview, but it still isn't working.

Comment: Since this is in `viewDidLoad`, which is typically only called once, you'll also need to set `self.tableView.backgroundView` to `nil` elsewhere in your view controller when you reload the table view. Basically, anywhere you determine that the contents of the table view have changed, you need to execute your logic that sets up your background image/color. (Also, it probably doesn't make sense to set `imageView` in two places, so I've updated the code in my answer.)

Answer (score 0):

*Use `self.tableView.backgroundColor` in both, may be its help to solve your issues*

```
if (sections == 0 || hasRows == NO)
{
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImage.png"]];

}
else
{
    [[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];   
    self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use then use this

```
    if (sections == 0 || hasRows == NO)
{
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImage.png"]];

}
else
{
   self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];   
    self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, and there is no difference. But I changed it in my question